# What is the correct and optimal way to get the return value of an executed stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, return-value

This is what I have and I was just wondering if this is the correct way to do this, if not, what would be optimal.

```
public static int AddPullSubscription(string connectionString)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@RETURN_VALUE", SqlDbType.Int);
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                return Convert.ToInt32(returnParameter.Value);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends a little on how the stored procedure works, not all of them use out parameters.  But if this works for you than go for it, there's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());` should do the trick.

Comment: @CodingGorilla, the return value that I want to get is the default value that you get when running a stored procedure. 0 for no errors and anything else for errors.

Comment: @MarkRucker The keyword `throw` just re-throws the same exception that was caught.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla I didn't know that. When it wasn't specified I thought it threw a new exception. Thank You!

Comment: @MarkRucker From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx - `A throw statement can be used in a catch block to re-throw the exception that is caught by the catch statement.`

Comment: It also depends what Database technology you are using. Not all SP are the same, or return the same. For instance, you do not get a returned RecordSet in Oracle the same way you do in SQL Server.

Comment: All, I'm trying to get the Return "Code" from the stored procedure to see if it was successful or not. If a stored procedure is successful, it returns a 0. Otherwise, a different number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the result of your Stored Procedure.

1. ExecuteNonQuery: If you need just the number of affected rows. AFAIK, it works if you didn't use `Set NoCount on` in your SP. Of course, for performance purpose keep that on. You can use `@Return_Value` as you did to get an integer value though. An [example](http://geekswithblogs.net/bullpit/archive/2009/01/02/how-to-get-a-return-value-from-a-stored-procedure.aspx).
2. ExecuteScalar: If you are after to select just a value of any supported type in SQL. An [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).
3. ExecuteReader: Moving forward through the selected record(s). An [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx).

Also take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2006/06/14/631923.aspx) that is about catch(Exception).

Answer (score 0):

You can use also `ExecuteScalar` (Sample with integer)

var result  = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: I was told that executeScalar does not return the actual return value of the sp.

Comment: yes i know but i propose an another answer for you, your code is good

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try:

```
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SEL_StoredProcedure", conn))
        {
                sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Id);
                sqlCmd.Connection.Open();

                return cmd.ExecuteScalar() as Int32;
        }
    }
```